# Centering UIBarButtonItem in a UIToolbar and adding custom text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I need to add a button to the center of the ToolBar. I have done the adding the button to the toolbar part successfully. My problems are as follows;

**1.) I need to center this barbutton. It should be in the center of the Tool Bar**

**2.) I need to have a text after the refresh button image is displayed.**

```
toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , 320 , 60)];

    NSMutableArray* button = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshButtonAction:)];

    [button addObject:barButton];

    [toolBar setItems:button animated:NO];

    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];
```

Answer (score 17):

**1.** Add flexible spacers before and after your bar button in the toolbar items array:

```
toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , 320 , 60)];

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshButtonAction:)];

NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace, barButton, flexibleSpace];

[toolBar setItems:toolbarItems animated:NO];

[self.view addSubview:toolBar];
```

Configuring toolbars is much easier to do in Interface Builder. If your view controller is inside a `UINavigationController` stack, you can still use IB to create an outlet collection of `UIBarButtonItem`s and set `self.toolbarItems` in `-viewDidLoad`.

**2.** To get custom content in a toolbar you can create a bar button item with a custom view:

```
UIView *customView = <# anything, could be a UILabel #>;
UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customView];
```

Comment: ok i am new to iOS. this is about `answer (2)`. By saying `<# anything, could be a UILabel #>` did you mean `UIView *customView = [UILabel alloc] initWithRect:....]` something like this ?? (sorry i am a newbie)

Comment: Yeah, sorry. `UILabel` is a subclass of `UIView` so if that suits your needs, create one and use it. If you need something more complicated, build up your own custom `UIView`. You can also do this in IB ;)

Comment: Well the problem is i need `UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh` followed by a text. So will your approach work since i will be saving `initWithBarButtonSystemItem` to add the `refresh logo` and then i can't say `initWithCustomView` to add the `UIView` that contains the label.

Comment: System items can't really be customized--you're going to have to create a second item to display the text, or use a single custom item with your own refresh button and text.

Answer (score 1):

I know this can be done in IB, but I believe if you want to center a button, you will need to add a fixed or flexible space button on either side to keep your button in the middle. If you are going to do this with just code... try and sandwich your button between the 2 space buttons.

Comment: Yes, i have to do it by code :( . Can you show me a sample code thats shows how to achieve this ?